# Calculate the difference in dates with SQL

Tags: sql, dbeaver

Im trying to use Mockaroo to generate random data for my database. Im trying to get two random dates and calculate the difference between the two as a third column. Does anyone have knowledge on how to do this. I tried to do a formula but it throws an error.

[image]

Id like DurationOfLease to be a result of EndDate - StartDate

Here is the error
Syntax error in formula `DATEDIFF(year, StartDate, EndDate) AS DateDiff;`

Comment: Any time “it throws an error” you need to tell us what the error is.

Comment: BTW: databases dont *throw errors*. They just roll back the transaction.

Comment: Sorry ~ 'Syntax error in formula ''DATEDIFF(year, StartDate, EndDate) AS DateDiff;'''

Comment: Can you post the whole query? That syntax looks correct and in line with the documentation for DATEDIFF. It is possible that there is something wrong in another part of the query.
In general, it is always better to post code, not just an image. An image can help us visualize the concept you have, but the code is what you're trying to fix.

Comment: I am looking at the results, there's indeed a few syntax errors from Mockaroo itself. However, I would say that there's either something missing or this feature in itself is not very reliable. I have tried to calculate several differences of years, months and days and all of them return as 0 even if it compares dates like 2020-07-01 and 1950- 01- 20

Comment: Take out the `As DateDiff;` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, So I looked a bit more into it.

First of all, the correct name of the function in Mockaroo is `DIFF_DATE`, not DIFFDATE.

Secondly, notice how your datetime fields actually show a date range each? Mockaroo Datetime fields generate data between that range, it seems like it considers them two separate columns.

So the syntax is failing because Mockaroo is interpreting your usage of both `startDate` and `endDate` to be a total of 4 dates. If you use only `date_diff('years', startDate, startDate);` it no longer gives a syntax error.

However, I'm testing the data and it doesn't really seem to return the correct difference either, but maybe it's different with your data. Try it out with that formula instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing research {no answer} for users (like me) on early DBEAVERS who may be trying to find workarounds:
on dbeaver 5.3.5,
select datediff('2024-01-05','2024-01-01');
gives the answer, but
select datediff(YEAR,'2024-01-05','2024-01-01');
gives the incorrect parameter count error.

also BTW, datediff does NOT appear in the drop-down context-aid.